# DotNet Core run test once at time

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, github-actions

I'm looking for a way for my xUnits to run tests one at a time (dotnet test (version core 6)). Both from code and configuration.

In particular, the tests will have to be launched via an action on github

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `xunit.runner.json` file:

```
{
  "parallelizeAssembly": false,
  "parallelizeTestCollections": false
}
```

And then in your `csproj`

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="xunit.runner.json"> 
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

You can also write in code

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Just exactly what I have been looking for.